# Protobuf.net Portable Exception - Timeout while inspecting metadata

Tags: c#, protobuf-net, portable-class-library

I am using the portable protobuf-net.dll version 2.0.0.668

My units test keep throwing this error:

```
ProtoBuf.ProtoException : Timeout while inspecting metadata; this may indicate a deadlock. This can often be avoided by preparing necessary serializers during application initialization, rather than allowing multiple threads to perform the initial metadata inspection; please also see the LockContended event
```

I've tried the following without success:

```
Serializer.PrepareSerializer<ParametersSetRequestMessage>();
```

There is no threading in the tests. And the types being serialized are not complex.

```
[ProtoContract]
public class ParametersSetRequestMessage: Message, IParameterMessage
{
    public ParametersSetRequestMessage()
    {
        Type = MessageType.ParametersSetRequest;
        BaseType = BaseMessageType.Command;
    }
    public MessageType Type { get; protected set; }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public List<ParameterSlim> SetParameters { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ParameterSlim
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public ParameterId ParameterId { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public byte[] RawBytes { get; set; }
}


[ProtoContract]
public class Message : IMessage
{
    public BaseMessageType BaseType { get; protected set; }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public DateTime ReceivedTime { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - for my unit test project I added the non portable nuget package and now everything if fine now.
There seems to be an issue with the portable dll. Although I have been using it on ios, Android and mono without issues. My unit tests are run on a windows machine.